# Pass multiple charts to Print Preview

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple sheets that have charts as objects.  I currently print these automatically by printing each one individually, to get around automatic duplexing.  The automatic printing works OK but is a little slow due to all the formatting I am doing, I believe.

This is the print macro for one group right now, the first three are charts and the last printout is a table:

```
Sub Print99()

    Call Module1.Start
    Call METRICS.MetricsOpen
    Call Module1.ScrapProdOpen

    Sheets("99i").Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("99i").Activate
    With ActiveChart.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = "&D"
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .ChartSize = xlScreenSize
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = True
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False

    Sheets("99p").Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("99p").Activate
    With ActiveChart.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = "&D"
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .ChartSize = xlScreenSize
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = True
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False

    Sheets("99s").Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("99s").Activate
    With ActiveChart.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = "&D"
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .ChartSize = xlScreenSize
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = True
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False

    Sheets("99w").Activate
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False

    Sheets("HOME").Activate

    Call Module1.CloseMetrics
    Call Module1.Finish


End Sub
```

I would like to pass all the chart objects as well as the table to Print Preview together at once so the user can have more control over the printing.  I am not sure how to select objects from multiple sheets so I may need to change back to the previous workbook setup where the charts were individual sheets instead of pasted on the sheet.

The alternative would be to significantly speed up the print macro but I also have an issue with `Application.PrintCommunication = True` where it causes an issue on Excel 2007 but runs fine on Excel 2013, and not all users are on 2013.